# REVERSE() email addresses before storing/indexing, or not?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, email, indexing

A db table will store lots of email addresses in one of the columns.
There will be often lookups of individual addresses by that column, so I'll set an index on that column. Only full addresses are going to be searched for, no parts or LIKE's.

Which makes more sense, in terms of performance: to store addresses reversed, i.e. 'moc.liamg@tset' or keep them straight, i.e. 'test@gmail.com'?

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario, the index tree in reversed case would have less root brunches, and is more structured overall - maybe faster searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you regularly query for partial email domains (i.e. the part after the `@`), reversing *could* make some sense in an indexed column.

This way the DB engine can use the index with queries like this one:

```
... WHERE ReverseMail LIKE REVERSE('.com') + '%'
```

If you query for *full domains* most of the time, just create a separate column that contains the domain only and index this one. Index lookups against an `=` operator will be faster than those against a `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Search is for complete email addresses only.
No parts, zones or domains.

Comment: @Serg: Why would you want to reverse it, then? If your concern is with performance, there are two things to consider: **a)** Don't over-engineer it. Unless you have extensive knowledge of the inner workings of string indexes on that particular DB engine, don't try to cleverly solve a problem that might not eben be there. **b)** If you are unsure, create a test case with a few million rows and find out the individual timings. My bet would be that it makes no difference.

Comment: My guess is that reversing the email address actually slows down the search (a bit), because there will be many identical prefixes. But as @Tomalak wrote, guessing about performance issues may be interesting, but not useful, you have to test in the actual environment. I am not sure however why do you want to spend your time on this. Do you have an actual performance problem?

Comment: @Hontvári: I'm guessing the same thing, it might even account for a slow-down. Anyway, you're right: guesses are a bad reason for such questionable optimizations.

Comment: @Tomalak: I appreciate your thoughts. I was asking the question in a guess (too), that a best practice of this kind maybe exists. Reversed email seems more 'natural' for indexing as it has more order initially. As I don't have a 1bln real email addresses to test on, its hard to test.

Comment: For direct find value, it will be slower because the index will be heaped all together, for direct searches you want the index to be spread out fast. Imagine if you had most users on the same domain (eg: company domain or gmail / hotmail etc) you would then need to search through `moc.elpmaxe@` before you start searching at something that is unique just because you're searching for `x@example.com` as opposed to searching for the first character and eliminating 25/26 of the branches instantly

Comment: @Seph Exactly my reasoning, thanks for outlining it. -- Serg, these pseudo-optimizations based on incomplete understanding of technical details and unfounded assumptions are pointless. Unless you have an actual problem to solve, you're wasting your time. And if you don't have millions of records, doubly so.